# TypeError: usert.addItem is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, discord.js

Trying to make a discord bot using discord.js. I'm using sequelize and sqlite to create a database to store data. A custom function doesn't seem to work, the terminal thinks it's not a function when actually defined. There could be a really obvious solution to this, but I'm very amateur, and I get errors often, but usually fix them. This one I can't even determine the root of the problem

This problem also applies to other custom functions

The most confusing bit is that, for another folder for another bot entirely, with very similar code and essentially the same custom functions, it works! But for some reason, it doesn't work here.

```
// Defining these 
const { Users, ItemDB } = require('./dbObjects');



// The command that uses the function. It is worth noting that it finds the item and user successfully, proving that the problem is in users.addItem
const item = await ItemDB.findByPk(1);
const usert = Users.findByPk(message.author.id);
usert.addItem(item);

// The addItem function defined, in dbObjects file
Users.prototype.addItem = async function(item) {
const useritem = await UserItems.findOne({
    where: { user_id: this.user_id, item_id: item.id },
});

if (useritem) {
    useritem.amount += 1;
    return useritem.save();
}

return UserItems.create({ user_id: this.user_id, item_id: item.id, amount: 1 });
};
```

The expected result is successfully adding to the database, but instead the terminal returns:

```
(node:21400) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: usert.addItem is not a function
```

Adding `await` before `Users.findByPk` returns as random.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await Users.findByPk(message.author.id);`

```
const { Users, ItemDB } = require('./dbObjects');



// The command that uses the function. It is worth noting that it finds the item and user successfully, proving that the problem is in users.addItem
const item = await ItemDB.findByPk(1);
const usert = await Users.findByPk(message.author.id);
usert.addItem(item);

// The addItem function defined, in dbObjects file
Users.prototype.addItem = async function(item) {
const useritem = await UserItems.findOne({
    where: { user_id: this.user_id, item_id: item.id },
});

if (useritem) {
    useritem.amount += 1;
    return useritem.save();
}

return UserItems.create({ user_id: this.user_id, item_id: item.id, amount: 1 });
```

Comment: Returns null when doing this

Answer (score 0):

Since `Users.findByPk(message.author.id)` is a promise it returns execution to the next sequence code, so therefore the variable `const usert` is not yet initialized which results in `usert.addItem()` not being function.

You need to change `const usert = Users.findByPk(message.author.id)` to this for `usert` to be fully initialized, the `addItem()` function will be available then:

```js
const usert = await Users.findByPk(message.author.id);
```

Comment: Doing this returns usert as null

Comment: check message.author.id if it holds the primary key id. if it holds then check your database table to see if the id exist.

Comment: I don’t understand? The same exact line works on a different folder, but still returns null here